# SQL Syntax for testing objects before creating views & functions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to figure out the syntax for creating a view (or function) but only if a dependent CLR assembly exits.

I've tried both

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = 'MyCLRAssembly') 
begin
create view dbo.MyView as select GETDATE() as C1
end
```

and

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.assemblies WHERE name = 'MyCLRAssembly') 
create view dbo.MyView as select GETDATE() as C1
go
```

Neither work. I get

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'view'.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is workaround**

```
if object_id('MyView','V') is null
    exec ( 'create view dbo.MyView as select GETDATE() as C1' )
```

Comment: But the work-around is broken. It means I don't get syntax checking/color formatting on my view code at design time.

Answer (score 1):

This is strange for me, but what I see in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) is "CREATE VIEW must be the first statement in a query batch." So it looks like you cannot create views inside IF statement.